# Why is InsertChildAt not enabled in release

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to arrange some widgets in runtime in Ue4. A function that does the job seems to be [InsertChildAt()](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/UMG/Components/UPanelWidget/InsertChildAt/). But it seems to only work in editor and not in release. Is there any reason for this or is it safe to edit the engine code to make it enabled in release.

Documentation states

```
This does not update the live slate version, it requires a rebuild of the whole UI to see a change.
```

But it does not say why.

Comment: I can't really comment on the code itself too much. Looks pretty simple though in the sense it just shifts some pointers in an array. I do wonder if shifting them is enough at runtime or if you'd need to call something like `UPanelWidget::InvalidateLayoutAndVolatility` after. In terms of editing the engine, the main reason not to is it'll make engine updates harder to integrate the more changes you have. The typical way to solve this issue if it's relevant is instead to inherit `UPanelWidget` and add your own runtime version there.

Comment: Yes it does look inocent indeed. I was just curious as to why it was disabled as default. Thanks for the tip with `UPanalWidget::InvalidateLayoutAndVolatility` i might try that if there is a problem